# Access Map value, Error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY

Tags: trigger, email

Full Error Message:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, CaseCountAlertTrigger: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: accId

External entry point: []
```

My Trigger is will send an email message if 7 Cases are created within 8 days.  I have a Map created within a for loop:
`accountIdEmailmessageMap.put(accId, messageToSend);`

For each AccountId, the String message that will be HTML is the value in the map.

How do I access the `messageToSend` which is a value in the map so that I can apply it as the body of the email?

```
trigger CaseCountAlertTrigger on Case (after insert, after update) {
List<String> emailAdds = new List<String>();                            // Holds '2' ToAddresses from Milestone1_project__c object
Set <Id> AcctIds = new Set <Id>();                                      //Holds Account Ids from this Case Trigger  
Id accId;


Set<Id> workCasesIds = new Set<Id>();   //Account Ids for Cases in the Trigger

 // SYstem.debug('Account Ids to send email for: ' + workCasesIds);   ---This works
List <AggregateResult> AggregateResultList = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name name, COUNT(Id) co
                                                    FROM Case
                                                    WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7 AND Id in :Trigger.New
                                                    GROUP BY Account.Name, AccountId
                                                    HAVING COUNT(Id) >= 8];

    Map < Id, String > accountIdEmailmessageMap = new Map < Id, String > (); // map of AccountId and Email body per Account/AccountId to be sent



for (AggregateResult aggr: AggregateResultList){ 
      System.debug('First cycle: ' + aggr);
                  String  messageToSend = 'You are receiving this email alert due to an account ';
                       messageToSend += 'activity rule has exceeded 8 cases created within 5 business days.<br><br>';
                       messageToSend += 'Please, follow up with the account and provide guidance and assistance.<br><br>';
                       messageToSend += '<b>Account Name:  </b>' + aggr.get('name') + '<br> <br>';
                       messageToSend +=  'Thank you, <br>';
                       messageToSend +=  'Salesforce Team';

             //Crete Map of <AccountId, Message to serve as body in Email
             //                         for each accountId>       
                 accId = (Id) aggr.get('AccountId');
                System.debug('THe accountID in the questionblock is: ' + accId);
                accountIdEmailmessageMap.put(accId, messageToSend);

            //Create List of AccountId's to cycle through and grab email addresses from
            //child Object for 'Implementation' Status emails   
                AcctIds.add(accId);  

}  

    // SOQL to grab the four status fields on Account to check status either 'Active' or 'Implementation'
    // also grab two email addresses for use in ifElse block
    List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name, Eyefinity_EHR_Status__c, Eyefinity_PM_Status__c,
                                    Project_Imp_Status__c, OfficeMate_Status__c,
                                        (select Client_Advisor_Email__c,
                                         Resource_Coordinator_Email__c
                                         from Projects__r) 
                             FROM Account
                             WHERE Id IN :AcctIds];


    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstASingleEmailMessage = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();


    String messageBody = accountIdEmailmessageMap.get('accId'); //THIS IS THE MAP TO GRAB ACCOUT ID AND MESSAGE BODY********

    for (Account al: accList) {

        if (al.Eyefinity_EHR_Status__c == 'Active' ||
            al.Eyefinity_PM_Status__c == 'Active' ||
            al.Project_Imp_Status__c == 'Active'  ||
            al.OfficeMate_Status__c == 'Active') {

                //Grab the message to send from the Map to the AccountId 

                String messageBody = accountIdEmailmessageMap.get('AccountId');

                //Send Email to Customer Service if "Active"
                List<String> emailaddr = new List<String>();
                emailaddr.add('CustomerSuccessManagers@test.com');  

                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Eyefinity Salesforce Support');
                mail.setToAddresses(emailaddr);   
                mail.Subject = 'Notification:  Account Case activity rule exceeded';
                mail.setHtmlBody(messageBody);
                lstASingleEmailMessage.add(mail);
            }


            else if (al.Eyefinity_EHR_Status__c == 'Implementation' ||
                     al.Eyefinity_PM_Status__c == 'Implementation' ||
                     al.Project_Imp_Status__c == 'Implementation' ||
                     al.OfficeMate_Status__c == 'Implementation'){





                System.debug('Accounts: ' + al);

               //Send email to Coordinator and Advisor if in Implementation

                for(Account a : accList)
                {
                    for(Milestone1_Project__c p : a.Projects__r)
                    {
                        emailAdds.add(p.Client_Advisor_Email__c);
                        emailAdds.add(p.Resource_Coordinator_Email__c);
                    }
                }

                System.debug('Emails sent to: ' + emailAdds);
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage amail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                amail.SetSenderDisplayName('Support');
                amail.setToAddresses(emailAdds);
                amail.Subject = 'Notification:  Account Case activity rule exceeded';
                amail.setHtmlBody(messageBody);
                lstASingleEmailMessage.add(amail); 

            }  
            else{
                System.debug(AggregateResultList);

            }
    }


    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] r = Messaging.sendEmail(lstASingleEmailMessage);   


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as you may have guessed, is here:

```
String messageBody = accountIdEmailmessageMap.get('accId');
```

First of all, you'd want to use a variable (e.g. `accId`) and not a string (e.g. `'accId'`).

Second, this isn't the right place to try and do this, because you haven't entered the account loop yet. Instead, remove that line, and then fix the following line:

```
String messageBody = accountIdEmailmessageMap.get('AccountId');
```

Which should be:

```
String messageBody = accountIdEmailmessageMap.get(al.Id);
```